# Validating no white space in a password in rails using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
    (?=.*[^\\s-])       # Must not have any blank spaces
    (?=.{8,})           # Must contain 8 or more characters
    (?=.*[A-Z])         # Must contain an upper case character
    (?=.*[[:^alnum:]])  # Must contain a symbol
  /x

  validates :password_digest, presence: true, format: { with: PASSWORD_FORMAT }
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true

  has_many :companies
end
```

I'm trying to make an rspec pass that is testing the password validation.  I want to ensure that passwords with empty spaces come back invalid.  This is my code, but the spec is still not passing when I test a password with a space (the rest are i.e. eight or more characters).

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. What you need is a negative lookahead for whitespace. `(?!.*\s)`

```
PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
  (?!.*\s)            # Must not have any blank spaces
  (?=.{8,})           # Must contain 8 or more characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])         # Must contain an upper case character
  (?=.*[[:^alnum:]])  # Must contain a symbol
/x
```

---

It's rather odd to exclude whitespace from a password. There should be nothing wrong with it if somebody really wants to. Reducing the number of possible characters reduces the possible passwords, aka the ["entropy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Entropy_as_a_measure_of_password_strength), potentially making it weaker. Finally, complex password rules like this can frustrate people using password generators which can't always be tuned to follow all the rules.

Instead, leave security issues to the experts. Rather than rolling your own password strength checker, there are any number already out there. This also saves on development time, debugging, and maintenance.

[strong_password](https://github.com/bdmac/strong_password) which is based on entropy, and [password_strength](https://github.com/fnando/password_strength) which is based on rules. Both provide ActiveRecord validations. And if you're using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) there is
[devise-security](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security) and [devise_zxcvbn](https://github.com/bitzesty/devise_zxcvbn).

Comment: Cool!  I will look into that.  Thank you very much!